# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: magicalrecord

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

MagicalRecord   
NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m line 54
__67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke
```

sometimes it occured when I used `MagicalRecord`.